# Accessing native features from an externally served html page in phonegap

Tags: django, cordova

The views are generated from an form generator and are stored in  the server. When users require, they are served to them. Everything works fine except for accessing native features. Since `cordova.js` is not present in the server, it gives `404` error. I tried Putting `cordova.js` in the server. Didn't help. Stuck with this. How to go about this problem?

Comment: I can think of something like downloading and keeping the file (if the file is not found) in some folder within the device and loading it.

Comment: Which version of cordova are you using?

Comment: @Octavio version `2.5`

Comment: Try with version 2.1.0, I am using it on the server and I can access the native features of the device.

Comment: Does your question dome down to "How do I serve this static Javascript file in Django?"?

Comment: @Octavio Thanks, I'll try that. However I'm wondering cordova.js will still not be there, right?

Comment: @gertvdijk No. It boils down to how to serve web pages accessing native features in phonegap from a server.

Comment: @ranjjose What do you mean? You need to have the cordovo.js file in the server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've solved the problem. In-fact, as @gertvdijk was suggesting it had something to do with  static serving. I was using `src="{{MEDIA_URL}}\cordova.js"`. It should be `href="{{MEDIA_URL}}\cordova.js"`. Now it works. Both `2.1.0` and `2.5.0` are working. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use the `MEDIA_URL` and the media directory for javascript/css stuff. Media is meant for user uploaded files (never trust that for serving code), not for files belonging to your project source code. See the Django documentation on serving static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks, I'll go through the link.